# Find String in associative array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an associative array that stores values from csv file like this:

```
$file_users = fopen("Users.csv", "r");
while (($record = fgetcsv($file_users, 1024, ',""')) !== FALSE){
        $users[]= array($record[0] => $record[2].$record[3]);
}
```

record[0], record[2] and record[3] are the values from the columns, row by row.

Then this is my way to search a value from the array and print the result:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($users);$i++){
foreach($users[$i] as $username_matricula => $username_fullname){
    if($username_matricula === $some_string){
        echo "Found: ".$some_string." and the result is: ".$username_fullname;
        }#end if
    }#end foreach
}#end for
```

And it throws me the following warning:

```
Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach().
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to find a string in assoc array?

Comment: Can you please write $users array value? As per the error, $user array doesn't have the value or empty array.

Comment: the array is:                                                 Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            ["value_matricula"] => "value_fullname"
        )
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps this?

```
foreach((array)$users[$i] as $username_matricula => $username_fullname){
```

by adding (array) in front of the actual array you make it empty-safe. (no warnings)